# Linked List Array type 'NAME' (aka 'char [41]') is not assignable

Tags: c, linked-list

I am searching a name on linked list but I am having some issues

these are the structures

```
typedef struct list
{
    void *data;
    struct list *next;
} LIST;
```

```
typedef char NAME[41];


/*
irrelevant structure here

*/


typedef struct person
{
    NAME name;
    int age;
    float height;
    DATE bday;
} PERSON;
```

here is the function to find the person

```
PERSON *findPersonInDatabase(char *name)
{
    LIST *current = head;
    if (current == NULL) {
        printf("empty fam");
    }

    // PERSON* tryout;
    // tryout->name = name;

    while (current != NULL) {
        PERSON* p = (PERSON*) current->data;

        if (p->name == name) {
            printf("please");
            return p;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I Believe the problem I am having is related to this
when I check whether or data stored in type NAME == type char* it just does not work but when I print out the data inside these types I get the value I am looking for. My question is how can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to compare strings:

```
if (p->name == name) {
```

This compares the pointer address stored in `name` with the address of the first element of `p->name`.  This will always be false.  To compare strings you need the `strcmp` function:

```
if (strcmp(p->name,name) == 0) {
```

While this is a problem, it is unrelated to the error you got.  That is complaining about an assignment to the `name` field of a `struct list`.  Because this field is an array, you cannot assign to it.  What you probably want is `strcpy`, which is used for copying strings.  For example:

```
strcpy(p->name, "my name");
```

Comment: @vksdbvksbvk Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.